# Sending a PDFsharp document to WCF service and saving returns error "Cannot save a PDF document with no pages"

Tags: wcf, arrays, pdfsharp

I have a PDF document generated by PDFsharp and displayed correctly in the WCF client. The document consists of one page which in turn contains an image. Code for this is:

```
PdfDocument d = new PdfDocument();
d.Info.Title = "Temporary Passport Document";
d.Info.Title = applicant.ApplID + " " + initials + " - Passport";

PdfPage p = new PdfPage();
d.AddPage(p);
XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(p);
XImage img = XImage.FromFile(passport.AttachmentPath);
p.Width = img.Size.Width + 40;
p.Height = img.Size.Height + 40;
gfx.DrawImage(img, 20, 20);
```

The PDF document is saved into a byte[] using the below code (*d* is the PDFSharp document and *passport.PassportScan* is the byte[]):

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
d.Save(ms, false);
passport.PassportScan = ms.ToArray();
```

The byte[] is sent to the WCF service to save it. Thus I convert the byte[] back into a PDFsharp document and attempt to save it with the below code:

```
PdfDocument d = new PdfDocument(new MemoryStream(pPassport.PassportScan));
 d.Save(RecruitAidPathRoot + "100104 - JPD - John Paul Doe\\" + "JPD - file.pdf");
```

When the last line is executed I get the error "Cannot save a PDF document with no pages"

The document consisted of 1 page in the client, so the document in the service should also consist of 1 page correct?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you are calling has this signature: `public PdfDocument(Stream outputStream)`

The description reads:

> Creates a new PDF document using the specified stream.
>   The stream won't be used until the document is closed, at that time the document is saved automatically.
>   Do not call Save() for documents created with this constructor, just call Close().
>   To open an existing PDF file, use the PdfReader class.

Use the Open method of the PdfReader class: `public static PdfDocument Open(Stream stream)` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. I ended up going down another route. I saved the byte[] using File.WriteAllBytes.